# 'ERROR: cursor "C_2" already exists' when importing from Vertica using Sqoop

Tags: sqoop, vertica

I'm using the following command to import from Vertica using Sqoop:

```
sqoop import --driver com.vertica.Driver --connect jdbc:vertica://[host]:[port]/[db] --username [username] --password [pass] -m 1 --table [table]
```

This fails with the following error:

```
14/09/01 15:12:21 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
14/09/01 15:12:21 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
14/09/01 15:12:21 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM [table] AS t WHERE 1=0
14/09/01 15:12:21 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: com.vertica.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cursor "C_2" already exists
com.vertica.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cursor "C_2" already exists
```

I've tried various Sqoop options, and much googling but can't work out why I'm getting this error or how to resolve it.

It seems Vertica does have some limitations around cursors, as [stated here:](https://community.vertica.com/vertica/topics/java_multithread_copy_stream)

> Cursors are forward only and are not scrollable. Result sets cannot be
>   updated. A connection supports a single statement executing at any
>   time. If you want to execute multiple statements simultaneously, open
>   multiple connections. Because HP Vertica does not have stored
>   procedures, CallableStatement is not supported. The
>   DatabaseMetaData.getProcedures() and .getProcedureColumns() methods
>   return information about SQL functions (including UDFs) instead of
>   stored procedures.

So my best guess at the moment is that Sqoop is opening more that one connection with a cursor? But then again, I am only using one mapper, so I'm not sure this is the case.

Can anyone give me more information on why I'm getting this error, or how to resolve it?

Are there other connection managers that do not use cursors?

I'm using Vertica 5 with Vertica JDBC 4. Sqoop 1.4.5. `list-tables` works fine. Some error when using a custom query for the import with `--query`, so I think the SQL is correct. I get the same error on `export`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Vertica does not support setting the fetch size in JDBC. So when importing, this will work, as it disables the fetch size.

```
sqoop import --driver com.vertica.Driver --connect jdbc:vertica://[host]:[port]/[db] --username [username] --password [pass] -m 1 --table [table] --fetch-size=0
```

However, exporting still does not work, giving the same error. There is no `--fetch-size` option for export, so the only way to get round this was to write a Vertica connection manager for Sqoop.

The connection manager is very simple:

```
public class VerticaManager extends GenericJdbcManager {

    // driver class to ensure is loaded when making db connection.
    private static final String DRIVER_CLASS = "com.vertica.Driver";

    protected static final int DEFAULT_FETCH_SIZE = 0;

    public VerticaManager(SqoopOptions opts) {
        super(DRIVER_CLASS, opts);
    }

    protected void initOptionDefaults() {
        if (options.getFetchSize() == null) {
            // Vertica JDBC does not support fetch size, so we default to 0
            LOG.info("Using default fetchSize of " + DEFAULT_FETCH_SIZE);
            options.setFetchSize(DEFAULT_FETCH_SIZE);
        }
    }
}
```

It forces the fetch size to 0, and also sets the driver for us.

So when running sqoop, we now use this:

```
sqoop [command] --connection-manger com.example.sqoop.manager.VerticaManager ...
```

With this, all commands seem to be working fine.